# Visually apealing holologous transformation of a given contour

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, visualization

There is this problem which roughly says:

> You want to put a framed picture onto the wall with a cord to the
>   picture frame. The cord is a single one, and both ends are attached to
>   the frame. How do you need to put the cord around $n$ nails, so that
>   the picture can be taken down by taking out any of the nails?

For [my page about the picture frame problem](http://martin-ueding.de/en/physics/picture-frame/index.html), I would like to create another section about *four* nails.

The problem is that the path I have drawn is really complex and hard to see, even with colors:

http://chaos.stw-bonn.de/users/mu/uploads/2013-09-19/four.png

The important part is just the windings, not the actual path. Is there some way or program to move the path in a way that makes it the most visually appealing and easy to follow?

Comment: I believe that both tags are not correct for this question. Why did you tag your question with them ?

Comment: @Belgi I have no idea what the matching tags would be. Those were the closest I could come up with. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: Isn’t it a [braid group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/braid-groups)? BTW, what means “holologous”?